# Code Generator for wrapper classes

Tags: c#, testing, code-generation

Do you know of a tool that generates wrapper class based on another class?

EDIT: By wrapper class I mean a class which wraps all exposed(public, protected) properties methods events so that you can put any logic in the middle. My concrete purpose is use it to verify the behavior of the wrapped class.

Comment: What's your definition of "wrapper class"? For testing I'm guessing you mean one that exposes private/internal methods to the outside world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use T4 templating and write your own logic...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have used SmartCode it's flexible and customizable
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/SmartCode-Code_Generation.aspx

Comment: This now links to a page saying the article is still being written. Do you have any more information about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `wrappergen` http://sourceforge.net/projects/wrappergen/.

I could not launch the exe, I got an error but you might.