# Composition/Delegation in C#

Tags: c#, delegation

Okay, I need to use some third party library and the resulting code is hard to unit test, because the classes don't implement interfaces (i.e. I can't isolate my code from the dependencies it has on theirs, which in turn relies on databases and who knows what else).

My solution - wrap the third party classes in my own classes which have the same interface and contain an instance of the third party class. Easy enough, so far.

Question: is there any way to automagically extract those interfaces from the existing (third party) classes? It seems like I am going to be writing a lot of boiler plate code if I do it manually.

Comment: Take a look at this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564181/code-generator-for-wrapper-classes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a tool that does that exactly. But, the way I would do it is this. Take Reflector and reverse engineer the third party component. Take the code and "smash it down" to just method signatures. Then, with a small amount of tweaking, you have an interface. Not completely "no boilerplate", but it does remove a lot of the rote work.