# Is there any way to keep your entity clean?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The problem
Let's say we have a Person entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Pretty straightforward, nothing special to see here. Now that we have this entity, we want to fill it with data. We're going to create a new 'person'. We could just return this entity to our view so we can fill it with data and persist the whole thing. But this leads to multiple problems:

We probably don't want a user to pick his own ID.
We want the user to confirm his password, so we'll probably need 2 password fields.
We don't want the user to choose if he wants to be an admin or not (although that could lead to some cool experiments)
If we are changing our database (and therefore the entities), our forms will rely on entities that are different than we intended in the first place.

Comment: +1 - good question, one I will need to have answered by next week too. Could it be a case of inheriting from Person?

Comment: @Unknown: If you've got a block of code and want to format it nicely, you just put four spaces at the beginning of each line. Using reverse quotation marks is intended for inline comments.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what question you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What uo are talking about is a `MVVM` pattern, commonly used in `WPF`

You should have a model object for `View`: ViewModel
and model object for `Model`: Model

It *can* be encapsulated in ViewModel, like

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
   Person _person = new Person(); 
   public string PasswordUser {get;set;}
   public string PasswordConfirm {get;set;}   

  public string Name 
  {
     get{ return _person.Name};      //I assume Person has a Name property
     set {_person.Name = value; }
  }

  ...
  ....

}
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564181/code-generator-for-wrapper-classes) may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the entity in a view model. The view model supplements the entity with additional fields and behavior specifically needed by the view. In this case, it would incorporate the password confirmation field and related logic.